# Setting Calendar property on Domain Object

Tags: grails, grails-2.2

I came accross an interesting problem in my code today.
I am using Grails 2.2.0.

Here is the code

```
def user = lookupUserClass().get(params.id)
log.info "[update]user.subscriptionExpiryDate1: " + user.subscriptionExpiryDate
user.subscriptionExpiryDate = Calendar.getInstance();
log.info "[update]user.subscriptionExpiryDate2: " + user.subscriptionExpiryDate
if (user.subscriptionExpiryDate instanceof Calendar ) {
    log.error "***** Is A Calendar Instance ***"
} else if (user.subscriptionExpiryDate instanceof String ) {
    log.error "***** Is A String Instance ***"
}  else {
    log.error "***** Is Something else ***"
}

if (!user.save()) {
    log.error "[update]Error occured saving user. Errors are: "
    user.errors.each { err -> log.error err; }
    render view: 'edit', model: buildUserModel(user)
    return
} else {
    log.info "[update]Successfully saved user"
}
```

`subscriptionExpiryDate` is a calendar property in my `User` object.

When I perform the save I get the following error

> Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Calendar' for property 'subscriptionExpiryDate'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date: 05/03/2013

Could anyone please explain why I would be seeing this error for the above code as nothing is standing out

Comment: so which error message from the above is logged? If there is nothing after `Unparsable date:` the date is empty and therfore unparsable/invalid

Comment: I suggest you to use Joda instaead of Calendar. See [the plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/joda-time)

Comment: @moeti apologies, I didnt paste the full date, the date is printed out and is a valid date Sergio - thanks Sergio I will keep that in mind but I would be curious as to why my initial code is not working first

Comment: Your snippet seems to run fine in isolation.  Are you doing any data binding on the `user` object before the code you pasted?  If you are binding to the `subscriptionExpiryDate` property, you will need a `PropertyEditor` to do the `String` -> `Calendar` conversion

Comment: Hi Andrew, yes there is some binding going on before that point. Thanks for mentioning the PropertyEditor, I will have a look at that

Comment: @Andrew - I followed your suggestion and it worked a treat - many thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

This question has been resolved as per [Andrew's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228619/setting-calendar-property-on-domain-object/19726542#comment21471718_15228619):

> Are you doing any data binding on the `user` object before the code you pasted?  If you are binding to the `subscriptionExpiryDate` property, you will need a `PropertyEditor` to do the `String` -> `Calendar` conversion